# Use NGinX to serve static files or a file server

Tags: linux, file-transfer, webserver, http, nginx

I am very new to `NginX`. I wanted to use it both as a web server, and for file transfer operations.

I imagined it'd be something similar to the FTP server which can be enabled on `IIS`, however I understand `Nginx` is only meant for `http` and not for file transfer.

There are some guidelines which demonstrate using `vsftpd` with `NginX` for file transfer, but the more I think of it, I wouldn't want to use another FTP based server with its own authentication, configuration and security related potential issues, and I'd like to avoid that.

The web server and file transfer mechanism don't need to do much, just host a web page for a few users, with directory browsing and an ability to do file transfer operations. no issues with scale or load balancing.

I am not familiar with other technologies like `lua` or `OpenResty` or even `django` which come up when pondering this issue.

With only `NGinX`, what would be the best way to achieve this, having a web server which can also allow file related operations like delete and upload? With the exception of `ftp server` route, I'm afraid I am unable to obtain any clarity or a starting point towards further investigation. I also have a `SSH server`, which, while it may solve the security (encrypted) and auth (`PKI`) issues, I'm not certain if it can indeed be used by `nginx` and the resultant file transfer mechanism be somehow rendered in a web page.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to have static file hosting, but at the same time enable users to upload/delete files or directories, from the *same* interface? That sounds like you need a real web app that bundles everything, like a pre-configured document management system. Otherwise you'll only get the basic directory listing built into NGINX, or a separate infrastructure for which your users need their own client software (be it (S)FTP, WebDAV, …).

Comment: Maybe the static hosting was a bit off, I wanted to have a dashboard which a few users could browse, the dashboard would not have any complex bit of content, and it would have a button or something which would allow a user to view the directory listing, and be able to upload and delete files as well, all from the web page. I know user can view directory listing and download using nginx. but not sure about upload and delete through a browser. I had a look at https://www.yanxurui.cc/posts/server/2017-03-21-NGINX-as-a-file-server/ , but resources(lua based) haven't been maintained it'd seem.

Comment: So you *do* want a simple document management system! The link you've shown includes a custom-made PHP file, so anyway you're going to need some application on top of NGINX. Perhaps setting up a WebDAV server would be easier?

Comment: I'm not much familiar with `WebDav`, however, looking at https://www.cloudwards.net/what-is-webdav/, it seems that it can indeed be set up over `nginx`, can be used for File related operations, and can be used by Microsoft browsers as clients, apart from being able to use SSL. If this understanding is correct, then I can begin with this as a starting point. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. If you write it out as an answer, I'll accept it as one.

Comment: @slhck While I look at this, are there any other suggestions, or something else which i can consider, if, for providing only a `delete` and `upload` functionality, running a `webdav` server proves a little heavy-handed? Maybe the same `php` script or `node.js` solution...?

Comment: Seems `WebDav` has some security issues and there are restrictions (internal) on its use for WAN network traffic.

Comment: Sorry for the late follow-up. I am not sure which seurity issues you are thinking of – it's a fairly simple protocol based on HTTP. I think you need to explain your use case restrictions better, given that this is apparently a company network and clients are IE? Sure, some PHP (or Node.js or Ruby or Python or Go or …) script can do that, but you'd most likely have to write that yourself.